# <asp:TreeView> Add an additional information to treenode accessible via JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, treeview

Is there a way to add an information to the asp:TreeView, in the way that i can access it via JavaScript/Jquery?

My problem: I have to prevent via JQuery/Javascript (on client side) that checkboxes in an asp:TreeView are selectable in different subcategories (or parent-nodes grouped by a stereotype-prefix). It already worked when i asked for the TreeNode-Text with $(this).next().text();, because they had a prefix (stereotype) in the categories, but now i have to hide that information and cannot use it to check.

```
    $("[id*=TreeView1] input[type=checkbox]").bind("click", function () {

        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");

        if (isChecked) {
            zuletztSelektiert = zuletztSelektiert + $(this).next().text();
        }
        else {
            zuletztSelektiert = zuletztSelektiert.replace($(this).next().text(), '');
        }

        if (zuletztSelektiert != '') {
            // Welcher Stereotyp ist selektiert?
            var stereotype = zuletztSelektiert.substring(zuletztSelektiert.indexOf('«') + 1, zuletztSelektiert.indexOf('»'));

            $("[id*=TreeView1] input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                var currentStereotype = $(this).next().text().substring($(this).next().text().indexOf('«') + 1, $(this).next().text().indexOf('»'));

                if (currentStereotype != stereotype) {
                    var isChecked2 = $(this).is(":checked");

                    if (isChecked2) {
                        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                        zuletztSelektiert = zuletztSelektiert.replace($(this).next().text(), '');

                        alert('It is not possible to select elements of different stereotypes. \n\n Selected Items:\n' + zuletztSelektiert);
                    }
                }

            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi! Is solved it by adding the stereotype to the target URL, because i did not find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Okay because nobody know the answer i just did it by adding the stereotype as GET-Param to the links target URL and navigated to the -Tag in the treenode

```
   $("[id*=TreeView1] input[type=checkbox]").bind("click", function () {

        var selectedStereoType = $.trim($(this).next().prop("href").substring($(this).next().prop("href").indexOf("=") + 1));
        //return;

        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");

        if (isChecked) {
            //zuletztSelektiert = zuletztSelektiert + $(this).next().text();
            zuletztSelektiert = zuletztSelektiert + selectedStereoType;
        }
        else {
            //zuletztSelektiert = zuletztSelektiert.replace($(this).next().text(), '');
            zuletztSelektiert = zuletztSelektiert.replace(selectedStereoType, '');
        }

        if (zuletztSelektiert != '') {
            // Welcher Stereotyp ist selektiert?
            //var stereotype = zuletztSelektiert.substring(zuletztSelektiert.indexOf('«') + 1, zuletztSelektiert.indexOf('»'));
            var stereotype = selectedStereoType;
            var letzteMeldung = '';

            $("[id*=TreeView1] input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                //var currentStereotype = $(this).next().text().substring($(this).next().text().indexOf('«') + 1, $(this).next().text().indexOf('»'));
                var currentStereotype = $.trim( $(this).next().prop("href").substring($(this).next().prop("href").indexOf("=") + 1) );

                if (currentStereotype != stereotype) {
                    var isChecked2 = $(this).is(":checked");

                    if (isChecked2) {
                        $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                        zuletztSelektiert = zuletztSelektiert.replace($.trim( $(this).next().prop("href").substring($(this).next().prop("href").indexOf("=") + 1) ), '');

                        letzteMeldung='It is not possible to select elements of different stereotypes. \n\n Selected Items: ' + zuletztSelektiert;
                    }
                }

            });

            if (letzteMeldung != '') alert(letzteMeldung);

        }
    });
```

This is how i did it in C#.NET
treeNode.NavigateUrl = "URL?stereotype="+stereotype;